# How to apply a binary mask to a RGB image in R with imager

Tags: r, rgb, mask, imager

I have loaded in a RGB image with the imager::load.image() function.
I have also created a binary mask with the imager::threshold() function.

[RGB_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuXMX.jpg)   [Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQQMr.png)

I am able to apply this mask to binary images by doing this:

```
red_channel <- R(RGB_image)
green_channel <- G(RGB_image)
blue_channel <- B(RGB_image)

red_channel <- red_channel * Mask
green_channel <- green_channel * Mask
blue_channel <- blue_channel * Mask
```

However RGB_image * Mask does not work because the RGB image has more dimensions than the binary mask.

So I need either a function in R to apply a binary mask to an RGB image.
Or alternatively a way to combine a red, green, and blue image into a RGB image.

I have a very strong preference to do this in R and a light preference to keep using the imager package if possible.

Comment: You could look at `terra::mask` for this.

Comment: Could you add the image that is the result of your masking operations above so I can see if my `terra::mask` approach is worth reporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own question after some experimenting.
This function does the trick, it does depend on the imager package.

RGBimage should be an RGB image loaded in by imager:load.image()
Bthreshold should be a binary threshold consisting of TRUE and FALSE values.

```
apply_rgb_mask <-function(RGBimage, Bthreshold){
red <- R(RGBimage) * Bthreshold
green <- G(RGBimage) * Bthreshold
blue <- B(RGBimage) * Bthreshold
return(imappend(list(red, green, blue), "c"))
}
```